# Как получить доступ к ошибке mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Имеется вот такой код:

```
function addData($userName, $userMail, $userMessage) {
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','mypasswd','guestbook');
//формируем SQL-запрос
$query = "INSERT INTO `gb_message` (`username`,`e-mail`,`message_text`,`date`,`published`)".
    " VALUES('".$userName."','".$userMail."','".$userMessage."',NOW(),0)";
 //выполняем запрос на добавление в БД

 //Если возникла ошибка, то добавляем сообщение в массив, а переменную устанавливаем в -1
if(!$mysqli->query($query)) {
$error = $mysqli->error;
$globMessages['insert_error'] = 'Ошибка добавления: ' . $mysqli->error;
$mysqli->close();
return -1;
//иначе добавляем сообщение об успешном добавлении и переменную устанавливаем в 1
}
}
```

По идее, всё должно работать. Но, как только я пытаюсь получить значение `$mysqli->error`, эти поля сбрасываются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит и что с этим делать?

Comment: Удалил ответ.  Потестировал код `<?php

$ln = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123123");
$q = "SELECT * FROM crap"; 

if (!$ln->query($q)) {
    var_dump($ln->error);
    var_dump($ln->error);
    var_dump($ln->error);
}` вывело ошибку 3 раза. Ищите ошибку в другом месте. Может что то перезаписывает.

Comment: @E_p Это отладчик так влияет, похоже. При перезапуске скрипта без него всё получилось.